# Powershell; Import txt file, format it and export it to csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm in the process of automating my new hire account creation in AD possess. I have created my scripts to import a csv file and that all works great. But now I am trying to automate it even further by just copying the contents of the email HR sends me into a txt file then have powershell format each line as a new column then export it to a csv file I can run my other script on (eventually combining them into just 1 script) 
The email format comes in looking like this.

```
Username: Test User
Title: Sales
Department: Sales
Manager: Manager's Name
Similar User: CoWorker's Name`
```

I just want to copy and paste that into notepad and save it. then have powershell import it, format it like it is below and then export it.

```
   Username   Title  Department  Manager         Similar User
   Test User  Sales  Sales       Manager's Name  CoWorker's Name
```

I have been trying the import-csv and get-content commands but I am having no luck getting it formatted the way I need it. Any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach is to use [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) (the solution assumes that each line only contains exactly *one* `:`, and that the input file is named `user.txt`; PSv3+):

```
$userObj = [pscustomobject] ((Get-Content -Raw user.txt) -replace ':', '=' |
  ConvertFrom-StringData)
```

Since `ConvertFrom-StringData` requires `=` as the separator between the key and its value, `-replace` is used to replace `:` with `=`.
Since `ConvertFrom-StringData` returns a *hashtable*, cast `[pscustomobject]` is used to convert it to a custom *object*.

**Once the information has been parsed into custom object `$userObj`, it's easy to process it further:**

#### Further processing as *data*:

To save the information to CSV file `out.csv`:

```
$userObj | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Utf8 out.csv
```

This yields:

```
"Manager","Similar User","Department","Username","Title"
"Manager's Name","CoWorker's Name","Sales","Test User","Sales"
```

#### Further processing to *reformat for display purposes*:

The default formatting gives you this (which just *happens to* be very similar to the input:

```
Manager      : Manager's Name
Similar User : CoWorker's Name
Department   : Sales
Username     : Test User
Title        : Sales
```

`$userObj | Format-Table` yields:

```
Manager        Similar User    Department Username  Title
-------        ------------    ---------- --------  -----
Manager's Name CoWorker's Name Sales      Test User Sales
```

To get the desired field order: `$userObj | Format-Table 'Username', 'Title', 'Department', 'Manager', 'Similar User'`:

```
Username  Title Department Manager        Similar User   
--------  ----- ---------- -------        ------------   
Test User Sales Sales      Manager's Name CoWorker's Name
```

If you want to get rid of the divider line (`---- ...`) and of leading and trailing empty lines:
`((($userObj | Format-Table 'Username', 'Title', 'Department', 'Manager', 'Similar User') | Out-String -Stream) | ? { $_ -notmatch '^-|^$' })`

```
Username  Title Department Manager        Similar User   
Test User Sales Sales      Manager's Name CoWorker's Name
```

Comment: Thanks for all the extra info explaining what each command does and other ways to format the tables. it has been very helpful.

Comment: wouldn't `$userObj = [pscustomobject] [ordered]...` preserve the given order?

Comment: @LotPings: Intriguing thought, but: `The ordered attribute can be specified only on a hash literal node.`